# How to use NSScrollview?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, scroll

I can't figure out how to actually use `NSScrollview`. I dragged the scroll view object onto an `NSWindow` in the interface builder. I then dragged some `NSButtons` onto the scroll view. My question is:

How do I actually make it scroll down, for example, 2x the original height?

Comment: A scrollview only scrolls the height of its document view, so it won't scroll unless your NSButtons are "off-screen/view" and not visible unless you scroll.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course the user can scroll automatically using their UI. I assume what you want to do is to scroll programmatically.

A bit of background: An `NSScrollView` has a `documentView`, which is the underlying view that the scroll view shows a part of, and a `clipView`, which is the view that is shown on the screen. So the clip view is like a window into the document view. To scroll programmatically you tell the document view to scroll itself in the clip view.

You have two options on how to scroll programmatically:

- `- (void)scrollPoint:(NSPoint)aPoint` –– This scrolls the document so the given point is at the origin of the clip view that encloses it.
- `- (BOOL)scrollRectToVisible:(NSRect)aRect` –– This scrolls the document the minimum distance so the entire rectangle is visible. Note: This may not need to scroll at all in which case it returns NO.

So, for example, here is an example from Apple's [Scroll View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Scrolling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003463-SW1) on how to scroll to the bottom of the document view. Assuming you have an `IBOutlet` called `scrollView` connected up to the `NSScrollView` in your nib file you can do the following:

```
- (void)scrollToBottom
{
    NSPoint newScrollOrigin;

    if ([[scrollview documentView] isFlipped]) {
        newScrollOrigin = NSMakePoint(0.0,NSMaxY([[scrollview documentView] frame])
                                       -NSHeight([[scrollview contentView] bounds]));
    } else {
        newScrollOrigin = NSMakePoint(0.0,0.0);
    }
    [[scrollview documentView] scrollPoint:newScrollOrigin];
}
```

Comment: I think i may need some help, i copied the code above exactly, created the IBOutlet and linked it to the nsscrollview. However when i run the app the outcome hasn't changed. When i scroll in any direction it just elastically bounces back.

Comment: It sounds like your documentView is not any larger than the size of the clipView so there is nothing else "hidden" to show. If you want a fixed arrangement of things in your documentView you do this all in Interface Builder. On the left hand side open the disclosure for the Scroll View and click on the View inside. Then in the Size Inspector change the size to whatever you want. You can programmatically put buttons wherever you want in this view. You can also drag them in IB into the view but they can be hard to place: put them in and use the arrow keys to move them even into the hidden area.

Comment: I should note that you can use Interface Builder's "Simulate Document" under the "Editor" menu to see your scroll view in action before you even build your app.

Comment: wow thanks for the tips, really had no idea it was that easy ^_^